# What happens when SQL Transaction commit passes, but client timeouts/fails

Tags: sql, transactions

What is the expected behavior of SQL if the transaction is committed to the database, it is successfully written to the database, but client fails in some way (timeout, network problem) and the final information that transaction is committed never reaches the client. So the final state is: transaction is committed and the client time-outed or failed in some unusual way. Does this leave database in dirty state where client thinks that transaction is not committed or SQL will ensure that if this information doesn't reach client, the transaction will be aborted?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly commit it when you execute it, it rolls back. At least for Oracle databases, I would imagine other SQL databases do the same thing.

If you do explicitly commit and execute it and your client-side program crashes or something before it returns a result, it doesn't really matter as it's in the databases hand now, not the clients computer. You would just relaunch your client-side program and just see the results of your query there.

**Sources**:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm#CNCPT016

Comment: Well the problem is more complicated if the "client-side" is some service, so it has to be sure that transaction is completed. For example if the service is doing some increment to some value in database, and it time-outs, how do i know if the transaction is fully completed or it is rolled back. Based on this service has to do some retry for example.

Comment: @MarkoKrstic In this complicated situation, we can run 3 SQL queries to confirm if retry is required.
1. Run a SQL read query and store the result in-memory.
2. Execute SQL write/update query.
3. In case of SQLTimeoutException (connection-timeout), run the 1st query and compare result with previous result. If the value is update, retry is not required. Else, trigger retry logic.